# display of minus and plus in tkinter calculator

Tags: python, tkinter

Now I'm making calculator with python and tkinter, but i had one little problem. Minus and plus displaing in a really strange way and I don't think that it's looks cool.[Look at Entry in which calculation should happend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnnSS.png)

So, I just want to know how can i centered them (move minus a little more higher).

My code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Calculator")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

# Main variables
equation = StringVar()
equation.set("0")

equa=""

# Program functions
def ButtonPress(num):
   global equa
   equa = equa + str(num)
   equation.set(equa)

# Widgets
calculation = Entry(root, textvariable=equation, font=("Arial", 15,"bold"), 
bd=12, insertwidth=4, width=15)
calculation.grid(columnspan=4)
# Numbers
button1 = Button(root, text='1', command=lambda: ButtonPress(1), bg="gainsboro",bd=3,  padx=12, pady=5, font=("Arial", 13, "bold"))
button1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
button2 = Button(root, text='2', command=lambda:ButtonPress(2),bg="gainsboro",bd=3,  padx=12, pady=5, font=("Arial", 13, "bold"))
button2.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)
button3 = Button(root, text='3', command=lambda: ButtonPress(3),bg="gainsboro",bd=3,  padx=12, pady=5, font=("Arial", 13, "bold"))
button3.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky=W)
button4 = Button(root, text='4', command=lambda: ButtonPress(4),bg="gainsboro",bd=3,  padx=12, pady=5, font=("Arial", 13, "bold"))
button4.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
button5 = Button(root, text='5', command=lambda: ButtonPress(5),bg="gainsboro",bd=3,  padx=12, pady=5, font=("Arial", 13, "bold"))
button5.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W)
button6 = Button(root, text='6', command=lambda: ButtonPress(6),bg="gainsboro",bd=3,  padx=12, pady=5, font=("Arial", 13, "bold"))
button6.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=W)
button7 = Button(root, text='7', command=lambda: ButtonPress(7),bg="gainsboro",bd=3,  padx=12, pady=5, font=("Arial", 13, "bold"))
button7.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
button8 = Button(root, text='8', command=lambda: ButtonPress(8),bg="gainsboro",bd=3,  padx=12, pady=5, font=("Arial", 13, "bold"))
button8.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky=W)
button9 = Button(root, text='9', command=lambda: ButtonPress(9),bg="gainsboro",bd=3,  padx=12, pady=5, font=("Arial", 13, "bold"))
button9.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky=W)
button0 = Button(root, text='0', command=lambda: ButtonPress(0),bg="gainsboro",bd=3,  padx=12, pady=5, font=("Arial", 13, "bold"))
button0.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky=W)
button_plus = Button(root, text='+', command=lambda: ButtonPress('+'),bg="gainsboro",bd=3,  padx=12, pady=5, font=("Arial", 13, "bold"))
button_plus.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky=W)
button_minus = Button(root, text='-', command=lambda: ButtonPress('-'),bg="gainsboro",bd=3,  padx=14, pady=5, font=("Arial", 13, "bold"))
button_minus.grid(row=2, column=3, sticky=W)



root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your font choice is causing that. Choose a different font.

Comment: @Novel Oh, I try Verdana and now it looks nice, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to choose a monospaced font, e.g. you could try:

```
calculation = Entry(root, textvariable=equation, font=("Courier", 15,"bold"), 
bd=12, insertwidth=4, width=15)
calculation.grid(columnspan=4)
```